# Command Line to transfer file between 2 different servers in different networks

Tags: networking, command-line, batch-file, windows-server-2008, file-transfer

I would like to create a batch file for Task Scheduler runs every hour on taking following actions.

A. File "apple" in Folder "fruits" at Server A on IP Address/Network A.

B. File "apple" in Folder "fruits" at Server B on IP Address/Network B.

File "apple" from Server A will transfer/copy to Server B and rename as File "apple_bk".

File "apple" from Server B will rename into File "apple_20130101_bak". (combine time-stamp)

File "apple_bk" in Server B will rename back into File "apple".

Both servers are Windows Server.

Above are in different networks, how to connecting by using command line and transferring the file?

Answer (score 0):

This uses the current date - I have a feeling you want the file date, but that's not clear.

If it's run every hour then neither date stamp will be unique.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%

copy "\\servera\share\apple" "\\serverb\share\apple.bk"
ren "\\serverb\share\apple" "apple_%datestamp%_bak"
ren "\\serverb\share\apple.bk" "apple"
```